# Should I use AWS SES, sendmail or setup SMTP for my node.js application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, smtp, sendmail, nodemailer

My web (Node.js) application has a form that people fill out and send the inquiry to web admin (myself @ gmail).   I use nodemailer before when I wasn't on AWS. The old server has SMTP.   The amount of emails sending out from the server to my gmail is small, very small.

Now, I've moved to AWS EC2.  I would like to keep using nodemailer for sending out email in the code.  For setting up mail server or enable me to send out mail, Should I:

1) Use sendmail?  What's the drawback?  Will it be blocked by gmail?

2) Set up my own SMTP server (postfix).  But I don't need to do bulk email or receiving emails though...

3) Use AWS SES service.

Also, do I need to open up port 25 from my server in order to send out email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using SES. Amazon sets up the DNS records and adds signatures to the messages, greatly reducing the chance they will be flagged as spam. And it's easier to do than setting up your own SMTP server. There's even an Amazon [AWS SDK for node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/4656127103016393) that supports SES.

If you use SES you do *not* need to open port 25. You don't need to open any incoming ports; you connect to SES via a normal https URL. (You don't need to open any incoming ports to use SMTP or sendmail to send mail out, either.)

Comment: What if  you are using older software that MUST use the normal STMP and Port 25?  I have been stumbling getting this setup on AWS - anyone have a link on how to get this running?

Comment: @Nutshell
emails on Port 25 will be throttled by AWS. You can submit a request to stop the throttling on a certain machine. This si the Link:
https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Answer (score 1):

I personally would prefer running my own email/MTA server. It allows more flexibility and more control.

**BUT** it is up to you to decide if it **cost effective** in your case. Badly managed mail server is not a gain, it is a costly liability.

Answer (score -3):

You do need to USE SMTP, in your PHP script that's if you have one, you should somehow include the SMPT like this

ini_set ("SMTP","mail.internetprovider.com");
ini_set ("sendmail_from","yourmail@mail.internetprovider.co.za");

Then port 25 has to be opened as well, do you know how to do that? if not, to open the port you can type inetmgr in you run area after typing start then r, these silly instructions are not to make a fool out of  you but I am just nor=t sure about the level of your knowledge and I am trying to help.

Comment: I don't run PHP. I running node.js server though.
And I know how to open port 25 in AWS.  Just don't know if I need it for sendmail or SES.